# Can't call statically imported overloaded function when one with different parameters is defined locally?

Tags: java, import, static, overloading, adhoc-polymorphism

I have the following simple Java code:

A.java

```
import static a.A1.*;
import static a.A2.*;
class Main {
    public static int g() {return 999;}
    static {
        System.out.println("f('a'): " + f('a'));
        System.out.println("f(): " + f());
        //System.out.println("g('a'): " + g('a'));
        System.out.println("g(): " + g());
    }
}
```

a/A1.java

```
package a;
public class A1 {
    public static int f(char x) {return 1;}
    public static int g(char x) {return 123;}
}
```

a/A2.java

```
package a;
public class A2 {
    public static int f() {return 0;}
}
```

`f` is defined twice, with overloaded parameters. As you can see, importing both definitions of `f` statically and calling them works:

```
$ javac *.java a/*.java && java Main
f('a'): 1
f(): 0
g(): 999
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main
```

But when I defined `g` locally, as well as statically import it from somewhere, it didn't work. Here is the output when I uncomment line 8 in Main.java:

```
$ javac *.java a/*.java && java Main
B.java:8: g() in Main cannot be applied to (char)
        System.out.println("g('a'): " + g('a'));
                                        ^
1 error
```

Why?

I tried changing the local `g` to non-static, and removing the call to the local `g`:

```
import static a.A1.*;
import static a.A2.*;
class Main {
    public int g() {return 999;}
    static {
        System.out.println("f('a'): " + f('a'));
        System.out.println("f(): " + f());
        System.out.println("g('a'): " + g('a'));
    }
}
```

But it didn't work:

```
$ javac *.java a/*.java && java Main
B.java:8: g() in Main cannot be applied to (char)
        System.out.println("g('a'): " + g('a'));
                                        ^
1 error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is happening because the method named `g` declared in your class, is shadowing the method named `g` that is `statically-imported` on demand. See [JLS §6.4.1 - Shadowing:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1)

> A declaration `d` of a method named `n` shadows the declarations of any
>   other methods named `n` that are in an enclosing scope at the point
>   where `d` occurs throughout the scope of `d`.

Comment: Is there some way to fix it? I.e to have overloading work with a local method as well as an imported one?

Comment: @Dog Use fully qualified name. Don't statically import it. That's the only way.